# Multiple Broadcast Receivers in modular project

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working in an Android modular project.

I want to know if using many broadcast receivers to communicate between modules can affect performance or stability of the app.

Comment: Actually when you using Broadcast to communicate between module it can be limited data size tranfer. Because it can throw TransactionTooLarge Exception. Simple way you can using Event Bus pattern or Subject RxJava2 to communicate. I have use modulazation too but I recommend if you can using startActivityResult you should do it

Answer (score 1):

No problem with good architecture, Remember to find a correct way for transmissions, because the cell phone charge is affected